# How to customize legend icons in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, symbology

Under layers in QGIS shapefile polygon layers always seem to be denoted by right angled polygons which translates to the map legend in Composer. Is there any way to change the outline to a more representative shape, i.e. lakes don't normally have right angles.

ArcGIS has a feature under the legend options to substitute the symbol being used in the layer with a preferred symbol, e.g. square to rounded or "blob" shaped. I'm after a similar feature in QGIS.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure you can. I tried changing the whole layer symbol style, but the change didn't reflect in the composer legend.

Comment: The Composer legend can be set to auto update, or not.

Comment: Is this still an issue with QGIS 3.10?

Answer (score 2):

By default that's not possible.

My suggestion would be to overlay the default rectangle with a "blob" mask image. This way, the original fill color will still show and update in case you change it. Not optimal, but should work.

Comment: Thanks. When you refer to a "blob mask image" are you meaning post composer export, i.e. in photoshop or the likes not QGIS?

Comment: no, i mean adding an image in print composer